# Significant with more in one sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I would like to use the word "significant" with the word "more".

Here is my sentence:

> Estimating the model parameters using method A will provide significant 
>   more flexible models.

I fell my sentence is wrong, but not sure. Any help, please?

Comment: Do you mean “significantly more” as in “a lot more”?

Comment: @Mixolydian, yes. will it be correct?

Comment: You have to use the adverb *significantly* instead of the adjective *signficant* to modify the adverb *more*. This goes for modifying any adverb, adjective or verb (that is, you have to use an adverb. Adjectives can only modify nouns.)

Comment: @Mixolydian Thank you so much. I really just learned a new thing. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from my earlier comment:

Since it sounds like you want to express the meaning “a lot more”- You have to use the adverb *significantly* instead of the adjective *significant* to modify the adverb *more*. This goes for modifying any adverb, adjective or verb- that is, you have to use an adverb. Adjectives can only modify nouns.